# What is the purpose of the extra result parameter of atomicModifyIORef?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ioref, global-state

The signature of `modifyIORef` is straightforward enough:

```
modifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO ()
```

Unfortunately, this is not thread safe. There is an alternative that adresses this issue:

```
atomicModifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> (a,b)) -> IO b
```

What exactly are the differences between these two functions? How am I supposed to use the `b` parameter when modifying an `IORef` that might be read from another thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in a comment, without concurrency you'd be able to just write something like

```
modifyAndReturn ref f = do
  old <- readIORef ref
  let !(new, r) = f old
  writeIORef r new
  return r
```

But in a concurrent context, someone else could change the reference between the read and the write.

Answer (score 13):

The extra parameter is used to provide a return value. For example, you may want to be able to atomically replace the value stored in a `IORef` and return the old value. You can do that like so:

```
atomicModifyIORef ref (\old -> (new, old))
```

If you don't have a value to return, you can use the following:

```
atomicModifyIORef_ :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO ()
atomicModifyIORef_ ref f =
    atomicModifyIORef ref (\val -> (f val, ()))
```

which has the same signature as `modifyIORef`.

Comment: So, had it been `atomicModifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO a`, returning the old value, would have served the same purpose (and be simpler, IMO). Interesting.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why would I need this feature for `atomicModifyIORef` but not for `modifyIORef`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well, `modifyIORef` doesn't provide any atomicity guarantees anyway, so it wouldn't be that useful for it.

Comment: @chi That would have been simpler, but the current solution can do more things. For example, you could implement some form of atomic compare-and-swap that returns a boolean flag that indicates if the swap did happen.

Comment: Well, instead of `atomicModifyIORef ref (\old -> if swap old then (new, True) else (old, False)` you could do `swap <$> simplerAtomicModifyIORef ref (\old ->  if swap old then new else old)` -- the only downside is that you need to compute the pure predicate `swap old` twice. But this should be equivalent to your compare-and-swap (I think?)

Comment: So the point is, without concurrency I might as well use `old <- readIORef r; writeIORef r $ f old` if I want to keep the old value, whereas in the multithreaded case I _must_ use `old <- atomicModify r (\x -> (f x, x))` to ensure the new value actually corresponds to `f` applied to the old value, of which I get a copy in `old`. Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Exactly.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Did this post answer your question?

Comment: @safsaf32: well, eventually yes, though to be honest I think the point isn't explained very incisively here – if you can phrase a better answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understand this. Think of functions that follow the bracket idiom, e.g.

```
withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r
```

These function take a function as argument and return the return value of that function. `atomicModifyIORef` is similar to that. It takes a function as an argument, and the intention is to return the return value of that function. There is just one complication: the argument function, has also to return a new value to be stored in the `IORef`. Because of that, `atomicModifyIORef` requires from that function to return two values. Of course, this case is not completely similar with the bracket case (e.g. there is no `IO` involved, we are not dealing with exception safety, etc), but this analogy gives you an idea.

Comment: Interesting comparison. I'll nevertheless accept [dfeuer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39682119/745903) now since the “why is this needed for `atomicModify` but for `modify`” part was what this question was mainly about.

Answer (score 1):

The way I like to view this is via the [`State`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#t:State) monad. A stateful operation modifies some internal state and additionally yields an output. Here the state is inside an `IORef` and the result is returned as part of the `IO` operation. So we can reformulate the function using `State` as follows:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.IORef
import Data.Tuple (swap)

-- | Applies a stateful operation to a reference and returns its result.
atomicModifyIORefState :: IORef s -> State s a -> IO a
atomicModifyIORefState ref state = atomicModifyIORef ref (swap . runState state)
```